# Laravel PHP deciding which button was clicked in the form of a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have form that opens on default localhost:8000 in laravel . In this form i have three buttons "create task" ,"delete task" and "update task" . I want to open a specific view on click of any of these button through my Task_controller.My form is opening "/decide" route and this route is opening the Task_controller for taking decision.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1>TASK</h1>
   <form action="/decide">
   <input type="submit" name="cbtn" value="create task">
   <input type="submit" name="ubtn" value="update task">
   <input type="submit" name="dbtn" value="delete task"> 
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

My route file goes like this

```
     Route::get('/', function () {
           return view('task');
     });

     Route::get('/create_task', function () {
           return view('create_task');
     });

     Route::get('/decide', "Task_Controller@decide");
```

and my controller file goes like this

```
     <?php

     namespace App\Http\Controllers;

     use Illuminate\Http\Request;

     class Task_Controller extends Controller
     {
     //
     public function decide()
     {
          $input = Input::get('cbtn');
          if (isset($input))
          echo "create button";
     }
     }
```

Right now with this code "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found" this error is occuring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;` to your controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class Task_Controller extends Controller
{
    //
    public function decide()
    {
         $input = Input::get('cbtn');
         if (isset($input))
         echo "create button";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel have no class "Input" in App\Http\Controllers\ namespace. You should use Request object to retrieve form inputs instead (it's better to use dependency injection instead of static classes).
Your controller should be like this:

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

 class Task_Controller extends Controller
 {
     public function decide(Request $request)
     {
          $input = $request->input('cbtn');
          if (isset($input))
          echo "create button";
     }
 }
```